# How to place single digital-signature on every page of pdf using itext

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

Basically, we are digital signing the document using some third party services which sign the document based on the Unique Identity authentication.

We get a digital signature for a pdf document hash, which we want to place on every page of that pdf is it possible using Itext...???

If possible, could you help with some sample code...

present we are using Itext 5.5.5

Comment: That's not allowed in PDF in general. You are asking something that is in violation with ISO-32000-2. I will close the question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm not aware of violation standards will go through that. I have seen similar implementation in one of application, we are trying to implement that. can explain you detail if possible on email..??

Comment: A digital signature in PDF covers the whole document. Signing separate pages is impossible. Old-fashioned people aren't used to that. They think that seeing a signature on every page is "more safe." That isn't true, but for psychological reasons (to comfort old-fashioned people), some companies add an ink annotation to every page *before* signing. That ink annotation has no legal value (only the digital signature has), but some people who don't understand digital signatures like seeing those ink annotations.

Comment: In the past, it was possible to match different widget annotations with a single signature field. However, the industry strongly recommended against doing so (already many years ago), and we removed that functionality from iText, just like we removed signature types of which we knew they were going to be deprecated. We value developers, and it is important that developers who create signing software produce signed documents that are somewhat future-proof. Now that ISO-32000-2 is released, meeting your requirement is officially no longer allowed in the current PDF version.

Comment: Haha..true..!!! My client is old thinks old fashioned way and  asked us the same...I tried to explain , clients doesn't listen right.so tried you guys is there a way, anyways thanks for the response